# SharePoint Calendar overlay with Outlook not removing/moving meetings

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I have a 6 SharePoint calendars that are intergrated with Outlook 2013. They are then overlaid on one Master SP calendar.

When a meeting is canceled or changed in Outlook they are throwing errors on the SP calendars.  A recurring meeting was "broken" and one mtg was moved to another date.  The meeting now shows up on the SP calendar as still blocked time but no title.  When you click on it you get the error

"Sorry, something went wrong 
Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."

Which would make sense but then the block of time should have opened up and not still "booked" on the SP Calendar.  Obviously if this is a 1 time occurrence, we can work around it, but it won't be, this will continue to happen.
Thoughts? 
Ideas?